# How to append the id of an anchor tag to a new href in jquery and replace the href attribute in a page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following:

```
<a id="sample"></a>
```

I want to change this to:

```
<a href="https://www.exampledomain/testpage.aspx#sample"></a>
```

using either jQuery or plain JavaScript. The "sample" is a non-unique, dynamic attribute, but the domain I need to 'pre-pend' to it is always the same value. Thank you in advance.

Comment: So you want to find all links with an `id` attribute, and add a `href` attribute with value `#id`? Sounds pretty straightforward, if you're having problems then please show us the code you've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `.querySelectorAll()` and `.forEach()`. This demo adds `href`, text, and `title` (shows full `href` value when user hovers over a link)

```js
var linx = document.querySelectorAll('a');

linx.forEach(lnk => {
  let ID = lnk.id;
  const host = 'https://example.com/#';
  lnk.href = host + ID;
  lnk.title = host + ID;
  lnk.textContent = ID;
});
```

```css
a {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<a id="ID0"></a>
<a id="ID1"></a>
<a id="ID2"></a>
<a id="ID3"></a>
<a id="ID4"></a>
<a id="ID5"></a>
<a id="ID6"></a>
<a id="ID7"></a>
<a id="ID8"></a>
<a id="ID9"></a>
<a id="IDA"></a>
<a id="IDB"></a>
<a id="IDC"></a>
<a id="IDD"></a>
<a id="IDE"></a>
<a id="IDF"></a>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I got it to work, only I omitted the lnk.textContent = ID; in this case because I wanted to retain the original text within the a tags. Thank you! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a jQuery solution. If you don't need this for every single link, you should update the anchor variable to use a class or other selector.

```js
var anchor = $("a");
var anchorTarget = "#" + anchor.attr("id");
var link = "https://www.exampledomain/testpage.aspx";
anchor.attr("href", link + anchorTarget);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="sample">Test</a>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I am getting an 'undefined'. Any suggestions?

Comment: @NotaryClasses `$('#facebook_link').attr('href', 'https://'+ i.facebook_link)` solved my issue

Answer (score 0):

You can set the href before and then removing the attribute id

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Titre de la page</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<a id="sample">Sample</a>
<a id="xxx">Sample xxx</a>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    function changeId(id){
        console.log(id);
        var a = document.getElementById(id); 
        a.href = "https://www.exampledomain/testpage.aspx#"+id;
        $('#'+id).removeAttr('id');
    };

    changeId("sample");
    changeId("xxx");
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const a = $("a");
const id = a.attr("id")
const host = "https://www.exampledomain/testpage.aspx#" 

 a.attr("href", `${host}${id}`)
```

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'a' has already been declared

Comment: Try switching const a to let a Sorry, I wrote this answer quickly on my phone - hopefully you can resolve this.